# LLVM Code generation causing seg fault?

Tags: llvm

I am interested in language creation and compiler construction, and have been working through the example here: http://gnuu.org/2009/09/18/writing-your-own-toy-compiler/.  The author was using LLVM 2.6, and after making a couple changes for LLVM 2.7, I got all the code generation code to compile.  When feeding the complier the test code,

```
int do_math( int a ) {
  int x = a * 5 + 3
}

do_math( 10 )
```

the program works correctly until it tries to run the code, at which point it segfaults.  I am in the process of building LLDB on my system, but it the meantime, anyone see an obvious seg fault in this LLVM asm?

```
; ModuleID = 'main'

define internal void @main() {
entry:
  %0 = call i64 @do_math(i64 10)                  ; <i64> [#uses=0]
  ret void
}

define internal i64 @do_math(i64) {
entry:
  %a = alloca i64                                 ; <i64*> [#uses=1]
  %x = alloca i64                                 ; <i64*> [#uses=1]
  %1 = add i64 5, 3                               ; <i64> [#uses=1]
  %2 = load i64* %a                               ; <i64> [#uses=1]
  %3 = mul i64 %2, %1                             ; <i64> [#uses=1]
  store i64 %3, i64* %x
  ret void
}
```

The output is just:

```
Segmentation fault
```

My arch is OS X x86_64.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got same problem. I stripped down Loren's compiler and everything was working fine except execution.

Segmentation fault was caused by the fact that:

> ExecutionEngine *ee = EngineBuilder(module).create();

returns NULL. To see the actual error, you need to get error string:

> std::string error;
>   ExecutionEngine *ee = EngineBuilder(module).setErrorStr(&error).create();

In your case you should probably see:

> "Unable to find target for this triple (no targets are registered)

To fix that you need to call

> InitializeNativeTarget();

But if you get:

> JIT has not been linked in.

You should include:

> llvm/ExecutionEngine/MCJIT.h

which will link JIT engine.

Answer (score 0):

The LLVM ASM you posted isn't a correct translation of the C code you presented.  You're allocating `%a` as a stack variable, and then loading uninitialized data from it and using it.  What you *want* to be doing is naming your argument `%a` and using that value. Try using this code instead:

```
define internal i64 @do_math(i64 %a) {
entry:
  %x = alloca i64                                 ; <i64*> [#uses=1]
  %1 = add i64 5, 3                               ; <i64> [#uses=1]
  %2 = mul i64 %a, %1                             ; <i64> [#uses=1]
  store i64 %2, i64* %x
  ret void
}
```

Also, your `main()` prototype might not match what your C runtime library expects.  And, beyond that, you do realize that you're not returning the result from `do_math()`, right?

Comment: The code isn't exactly 'C Code', it's a C-like language, that is built in the tutorial I linked to.  I understand that the 'do_math' function doesn't return the int like it says it should.  The ASM is generated from an AST and some code generation code, so I will see if I can find out why it's trying to use uninitialized data.